# Creating Smart Tag for Form (not other control) using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, smart-tags

As the Form of `System.Windows.Forms` inherits from Control, I was wondering if there is a way to create a Custom Form and its Designer with some options (shortcuts) to create a title or somthings like that.

I tried this, but nothings happend, the Form I calles `ManagedForm`

```
[Designer(typeof(ManagedFormDesigner))]
public class ManagedForm : Form{
   //code here
}


[PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")] 
public class ManagedFormDesigner : ControlDesigner {
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists;
    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists {
        get {
            if (actionLists == null) {
                actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
                actionLists.Add(new ManagedFormDesignerActionList(this.Component));
            }
            return actionLists;
        }
     }
}



public class ManagedFormDesignerActionList : DesignerActionList {
    private ManagedForm managedForm = null;
    private DesignerActionUIService designerActionUISvc = null;

    public ManagedFormDesignerActionList(IComponent component) : base(component) {
        this.managedForm = component as ManagedForm;
        this.designerActionUISvc =
        GetService(typeof(DesignerActionUIService))
        as DesignerActionUIService;
    }

    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems() {
        DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();
        items.Add(new DesignerActionMethodItem(this, "CreateTitle", "Create Title", "Appearence", true));
        return items;
    }

    public void CreateTitle() {
        Panel pTitulo = new Panel();
        pTitulo.Size= new Size(100,25);
        pTitulo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        (this.Component as ManagedForm).Controls.Add(pTitulo);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Action list are show when you click on the little arrow on the control inside a form (or on a component on the bottom of the designer if the object is a component).

Other things you can do is to manage verbs.
Verbs Handling is implemented on the ControlDesigner class (ManagedFormDesigner in your case).
You can see verbs clicking right mouse button or on the bottom of the properties (i.e. TabControl ha 2 verbs, add tab and remove tab).

You can implement verbs adding to ControlDesigner (or ComponentDesigner) class something like this

```
    private DesignerVerbCollection _verbs;

    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_verbs == null)
            {
                _verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();
                _verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Create Title", new EventHandler(MyCreateTitleHandler)));
            }
            return _verbs;
        }
    }

    private void MyCreateTitleHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do here something but take care to show things via IUIService service
        IUIService uiService = GetService(typeof(IUIService)) as IUIService;
    }
```